# Картинки по 3 в ряд

Tags: html, css, вёрстка

Нужна помощь, есть 7 картинок, нужно расположить их в 2 ряда по 3 и 1 снизу по центру, но еще под каждой картинкой нужен текст, что-то типо должности. Как это реализовать

Comment: grid\flex как вам удобней

Answer (score 3):

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.item {
  flex-basis: 33%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.item-box {
  text-align: center;
}

.item:last-child {
  flex-basis: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="item">
    <div class="item-box">
      <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150" alt="" />
      <p>text</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <div class="item-box">
      <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150" alt="" />
      <p>text</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <div class="item-box">
      <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150" alt="" />
      <p>text</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <div class="item-box">
      <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150" alt="" />
      <p>text</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <div class="item-box">
      <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150" alt="" />
      <p>text</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <div class="item-box">
      <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150" alt="" />
      <p>text</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <div class="item-box">
      <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150" alt="" />
      <p>text</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Ну как вариант flex (кажется можно и почище сделать)